# How to insert MAX function in a subquery? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL code that's shows me the number of selling per seller per sector.

```
SELECT        
    [JO_Info].Name, [Proc].Sector, COUNT([JO].JO_ID) AS total
FROM            
    [JA] 
INNER JOIN
    [Proc] ON [JA].ProcessID = [Proc].ProcessID 
INNER JOIN
    [JO] ON [JA].JO_ID = [JO].JO_ID 
INNER JOIN
    [JO_Info] ON [JO].JOI_ID = [JO_Info].JOI_ID
WHERE        
    ([JO].JO_ID = 'seller')
GROUP BY 
    [JO_Info].Name, [Proc].Sector
```

The output is the following:

```
    Name      | Sector  | total
   -----------+---------+----------
    Grace     |  1      |  4
    Elizabeth |  2      |  1
    Bette     |  3      |  3
    Angelina  |  4      |  6
    Karl      |  4      |  1
    Alberto   |  13     |  1
    Jorge     |  15     |  1
```

But I want the seller that sold more per sector. So, my question is how to insert the MAX function in order to get the following result (No repeats in the sector).

```
    Name      | Sector  | total
   -----------+---------+----------
    Grace     |  1      |  4
    Elizabeth |  2      |  1
    Bette     |  3      |  3
    Angelina  |  4      |  6
    Alberto   |  13     |  1
    Jorge     |  15     |  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by sector order by total desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: When I try your code it says that the table Sector "could not be bound". Do you know why is it happening?

Comment: is the column sector in more than one table?

Comment: Yes it is. How to get over this?

Comment: @GeoMaps Learn to debug.  It's part of programmer's job.  Have you tried just running the inner query???  If it works, then add the outer query.  I don't see why it shouldn't work.